# Как сделать в эффекте перелистывания страницы так, чтобы отогнутый уголок при наведении мышью сильнее отгибался и был всегда снизу справа?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Для эффекта перелистывания страницы использую плагин [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com/).
Актуальный пример:

```js
$("#flipbook").turn({
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    autoCenter: true,
    display: 'single'
});
$("#flipbook").turn("peel", "br");
```

```css
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}

#flipbook{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#flipbook .page{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:white;
    line-height:300px;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
}

#flipbook .page-wrapper{
    -webkit-perspective:2000px;
    -moz-perspective:2000px;
    -ms-perspective:2000px;
    -o-perspective:2000px;
    perspective:2000px;
}

#flipbook .hard{
    background:#ccc !important;
    color:#333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#flipbook .odd{
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.95, #FFF), color-stop(1, #DADADA));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    
}

#flipbook .even{
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, right top, left top, color-stop(0.95, #FFF), color-stop(1, #DADADA));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    background-image:linear-gradient(right, #FFF 95%, #C4C4C4 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -o-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    -ms-box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 5px #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js"></script>
<div id="flipbook">
    <div> Page 1 </div>
    <div> Page 2 </div>
</div>
```

Не могу никак понять, как его настроить таким образом, чтобы уголок при наведении-отведении мыши не выглаживался обратно, а при наведении сильнее отводился.
Плюс этот отогнутый уголок должен быть всегда внизу справа (а не так как по умолчанию во втором случае слева).